Vibration not working: Pixel 6a
This is not a duplicate of
Vibration not working on my android device, which pertains to Android 4.2
Device: Pixel 6a,stock Android, April security patch on Android 14.
Problem: After updating to April security patch, vibration stopped working.
Things tried to fix the problem (unsuccessful):

Toggled on/off vibration settings under accessibility.

Rebooted.

Problem persists in safe-mode. I denied vibration permission to all apps using Permission Manager X.

Scoured the internet. This issue has been reported and the solutions are what has been described above.


How do I fix this?

It's weird but the vibration problem is connected with Gboard settings! I don't use Gboard, so it didn't occur to me to check there first.
Under the Gboard settings: Vibrate on key press → Vibration strength on key press → set a custom value instead of default.
It took me considerable efforts to find the solution, hence posting it as a self-answered question. It may save someone time and efforts.

I think it's more complex than that. I have this exact problem on my 6a running LOS 21, so there's no GBoard installed. I use Heliboard, and I have a custom vibration duration set there, but no dice. There are long threads on Reddit, Github, XDA and the GrapheneOS forum about this issue.
